# I think someone copied the functionality from my code. Is that plagiarism and is that allowed on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

Have a look at the question [Can't figure how to get Input from html and set it inside js var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77769979/cant-figure-how-to-get-input-from-html-and-set-it-inside-js-var/77770062#77770062):

> Why it doesn't work?
>
> ```
> var TextcolorRGB = 'rgb('.concat(TextcolorRED + ',' + TextcolorGREEN + ',' + TextcolorBLUE + ')');
> //Apply
> document.body.style.backgroundColor = BGcolorRGB;
> document.getElementById("Text-Color").style.color = TextcolorRGB;
> ```

My answer:

> There is code for changing the bgcolor:
>
> ```
> //Set Colors 
> function Value() {
>   const val = document.querySelector('input').value;   
>   GlobalcolorRED = val;   alert(GlobalcolorRED);   
>   SetColor() } 
>   //EVRYTHING THAT WAS AFTER getVal() SHOULD BE DELETED UNTIL Color() function Color(){   function SetColor(){
>   document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb("+GlobalcolorRED+","+GlobalcolorGREEN+","+GlobalcolorBLUE+")"; 
> }
> ```
>
> Everything that was between Value() and SetColor() was unnecessary.

Answer from another user (published after my answer):

> ```
> var BGcolorRGB = "rgb(".concat(     BGcolorRED + "," + BGcolorGREEN + "," + BGcolorBLUE + ")"   );
> document.body.style.backgroundColor = BGcolorRGB;
> ```

The problem is that I posted the answer before them and I think that they copied the functionality from my code. Is this plagiarism and is this allowed on Stack Overflow?

Comment: No, plagiarism is not ok. I'm not an expert here, but if an answer is basic enough and short enough it can be very hard to prove plagiarism, especially if variable names are different.

Comment: I'm having a hard time seeing the overlap. The relevant parts of *both* answers seem to largely be the same as the question code, and the overlap between the second answer and the question seems larger than with your answer. Perhaps you should [edit] this meta-question to spell out what exactly you consider to be plagiarised.

Comment: If its really about the question linked by President James K. Polk, then the quote you show here are just two lines out of  a ~35 lines code block. And why does your answer contain a link to a jsfiddle when you could have also added a stack snippet?

Comment: Plagiarism isn't allowed.
But no, that ain't plagiarism.

Comment: Looking at the actual question, I’m having an even harder time seeing the issue. The gist of both answers seems to be "use a function to run the code once you have its input". If that’s plagiarism then you are some decades late for claiming to be first. If it’s not - please [edit] this meta-question to spell out what you consider plagiarised here.

Comment: I would further note that, the other answer coming only 7 minutes after yours, it's likely the other user didn't even know of the existence of your answer while theirs was being developed.

Comment: “Is this plagiarism” - No; It’s absolutely not plagiarism. Your answer doesn’t perform a string concatenation. I see zero overlap between the two slices of code. The variable names are not even the same or even close to being the same. Seems like your issue is that your answer wasn’t accepted by the author. **The other answer is significantly high quality.**

Comment: People should stop complaining that they are the only ones that can somehow come up with *trivial code*. Do you really think that you are the only one who can figure out "assign this string to this property"? Can you not understand how *dismissive* and *insulting* it looks when you are trying to claim that anybody who does some of the most basic code manipulation must have "stolen" it from you. Neither have you come up with anything original here or even noteworthy, nor does the other user need your and only your help to code.

Comment: If they plagiarized your code then you must have plagiarized your own code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323082/why-doesnt-backgroundcolor-rgba-b-c-work) ...

Comment: You in comments: "I just asked if it is a plagiarism I didn't want to claim anyone" "don't tell anyone that they claim others when they didn't do that" "I didn't discrimitate the guy that answered after me" Quote from your original post that got moved to the title (& that you left on your last edit): "**I think that he copied the functionality from my code.**"

Comment: Guys I just asked if it is  plagiarism because I was not sure, but telling me that I am *dismissive and insulting* was just impolite

Comment: You did NOT "just", and you did NOT say you were unsure of COPYING, and you were NOT told you were dismissive & insulting, you were ASKED to CONSIDER, "Can you not understand how dismissive and insulting it looks when you are trying to claim" something you DID claim. Please stop for a moment & read what you post versions & the comments actually say.

Comment: You felt that it was plagiarism, else you wouldn't have asked. Many here are telling you that the evidence is so weak, you shouldn't have even asked. Plagiarism is a serious charge (and yes, you *are* making that charge, whether you care to admit it or not), and best not to publicly ask about this without much stronger evidence. Period.

Comment: Besides all that... it's a couple of lines of javascript which changes the background CSS property. That alone should have made you think "hell no". There aren't a whole lot of ways to accomplish that through Javascript, the couple lines of code involved will bound to be nearly identical in all cases.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Plagiarism in general is not allowed on SO. But this is not such a case and the quote in this meta question is very misleading since it only shows two lines of code out of a ~35 lines code block.

Most of the code presented was already present in the question and the answer is sufficiently different from yours. The whole answer seems to focus on something else than yours, specifically that `applyColors()` needs to be called from an event listener.

I would consider something as plagiarized only when a significant part of one answer is copied. Especially when most of the code is from the original question, the answers are significantly different and posted in a short timeframe (7 minutes here), this is not enough to warrant any moderation actions.